# parameters r=0 , i=0 in a constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

so I was just learning about polymorphism in oops , I was being taught operator overloading in a program that adds complex numbers;
so there is this class and it's constructor but the constructor is like

```
complex(int r=0 , i=0){...}
```

my question is what does r=0 mean as a parameter ?
what I am guessing is when I don't pass the values in the constructor when creating an object then the program takes 0 as default value;

if so then can I do the same with normal functions ?

Comment: You've guessed right. And the answer to your question is yes. Note that you can define default values only for the last N arguments (e.g., in your case, you cannot define a default value for `r`, without also defining a default value for `i`).

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb so You mean to say that I can only define defaults values for all the parameters and not for some

Comment: No, you can define default values for some, so long as they are the last ones. For example, in your case, you can define a default value only for `i`. But you cannot define a default value only for `r`.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb oh ! ok , thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

The two main types of constructors are default constructors and parameterized constructors. Actually this is an example of [default constructor](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=only-default-constructors-c). Default constructor will not have any parameters or it may contain parameters with default values.

And Constructors are no return type functions of a class that are executed when new objects of the class are created. So surely you can do the same with functions.

```
void maxnumber(int i=0,int j=0){
   cout<< max(i,j);
}
```

So the above no return type function can be called like the following:

```
maxnumber();
maxnumber(0,0);
maxnumber(10,20);
```

Comment: You are missing a typical use case where you specify one argument only, e.g.: `maxnumber(5)`, where i=0 and j=5.

Comment: Well. If i=0 and j=5 are initialized in the default constructor, then calling `maxnumber(5)` will initialize assign i=5 and j will remain the same. And `maxnumber(0,5)` will assign j = 5 and i = 0.